# What is the `user` parameter in `pcap_loop` and `pcap_dispatch`?

Tags: c, libpcap

I have Google'd this a bunch, but I have no idea what the `user` parameter is for `pcap_loop()`. The best one I found online is from Stanford (link: http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section3.html):

```
    /* allright here we call pcap_loop(..) and pass in our callback function */
    /* int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user)*/
    /* If you are wondering what the user argument is all about, so am I!!   */
    pcap_loop(descr,atoi(argv[1]),my_callback,NULL);
```

The manpage only mentions the `user` parameter once (outside the actual parameters in the functions):

> ...three arguments: a u_char pointer which is passed in the user argument to pcap_loop() or pcap_dispatch()...

I find that very unhelpful.

I can pass any string in the invocation of `pcap_loop` and successfully print it out in the callback handler. Is this just meant to be a way the caller can pass a random string to the handler?

Does anyone know what this parameter is supposed to be used for?

Comment: It may be a deprecated argument no longer used but kept for backward compatibility.

Comment: @FiddlingBits That makes sense, but it would be interesting to know what it was originally meant for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - it's so you can pass in any custom data you need to access to from within your handler function, so you don't need a global variable to accomplish the same.

e.g.

```
struct my_struct something; 
...
pcap_loop(descr,atoi(argv[1]),my_callback, (u_char*)&something);
```

Now in `my_callback` you get access to the `something`

```
void my_callback(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h, const u_char *bytes) 
{
    struct my_struct *something = (struct my_struct *)user;
    ..
}
```

(Note, the `user` argument would be better specified as a `void*` , but is probably a `u_char*` type for legacy reasons)

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you so much.  *Now* I get it.